# Corectness of design using jUnit test classes implementing interface as template

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, interface

I have lots of simple classes implementing a simple interface:

```
public interface MyInterface<T> {
    public T value();
}
```

Naturally, I want to create unit tests for all of these classes. Assume the class `MyClass implements MyInterface<String>` and the following example:

```
public class MyClassTest {

    @Test
    public void valueTest() {
        assertEquals(new MyClass(...).value(), ...);
    }

    @Test
    public void performanceTest() {
        assertTimeout(ofMillis(1), () -> new MyClass(...).value());
    }
}
```

---

Well, this pattern would repeat lot of times, so applying a template would help me to simplify the job. However, I think using an interface would be better since the test class really has to implement all of the methods.

```
public interface MyInterfaceTestTemplate {
    public void valueTest();
    public void performanceTest();
}
```

And implement it in the unit test class:

```
public class MyClassTest implements MyInterfaceTestTemplate {

    @Test
    @Override
    public void valueTest() {
        assertEquals(new MyClass(...).value(), ...);
    }

    @Test
    @Override
    public void performanceTest() {
        assertTimeout(ofMillis(1), () -> new MyClass(...).value());
    }
}
```

---

My question are:

- What are pros and cons of this approach?
- Does this way follows the idea of test-driven development?
- Is it a good way of checking the unit tests validity?

Comment: I think using abstract test class and moving common test methods or helper methods to it would be better approach. Your approach just forces to implement those methods and it does not guarantee that they will have `@Test` annotation.

Comment: @tsolakp: Would you provide an example using the abstract test class as an answer? The point is all of the test methods have different implementation. Moreover, I can't picture how to guarantee these methods will have the `@Test` annotation (I think it's not possible at all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use a *parameterized test* of Junt5 (https://blog.codefx.org/libraries/junit-5-parameterized-tests) with you code:

```
@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource(names = "createInterfaceImplAndCheckValue")
void testValue(MyInterface impl, Object value) { 
    assertEquals(impl.getValue(),value)
}

private static Stream<Arguments> createInterfaceImplAndCheckValue() {
    return Stream.of(
            ObjectArrayArguments.create(new MyInterfaceImpl1(), "hi"),
            ObjectArrayArguments.create(new MyInterfaceImpl2(), 7));
}

@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource(names = "createInterfaceImplAndTimeout")
void testPerformance(MyInterface impl, int timeout) { 
        assertTimeout(ofMillis(timeout), () -> impl.value());
}

private static Stream<Arguments> createInterfaceImplAndTimeout() {
    return Stream.of(
            ObjectArrayArguments.create(new MyInterfaceImpl1(), 1),
            ObjectArrayArguments.create(new MyInterfaceImpl2(), 13));
}
```

Of cause you also may put all in the same "data method" method and simply ignore the parameters you don't need:

```
@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource(names = "createInterfaceImplAndCheckValue")
void testValue(MyInterface impl, Object value, int timeout) { 
    assertEquals(impl.getValue(),value)
}


@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource(names = "createInterfaceImplAndCheckValue")
void testPerformance(MyInterface impl, Object value, int timeout) { 
        assertTimeout(ofMillis(timeout), () -> impl.value());
}

private static Stream<Arguments> createInterfaceImplAndCheckValue() {
    return Stream.of(
            ObjectArrayArguments.create(new MyInterfaceImpl1(), "hi", 1),
            ObjectArrayArguments.create(new MyInterfaceImpl2(), 7, 12));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually it is advised not to inherit unit tests but I find it totally fine as long as you keep inheritance to one level and annotations on the base class to a minimum.

Here is a sample of what I meant. This might be too simplified but I am just working of your code example:

```
public class MyClass implements MyInterface<String>{

    @Override
    public String value() {
        return "hi";
    }
}

public abstract class AbstractTest<T> {

    @Test
    public void commonValueTest(){
        assertEquals( createInstance().value(), getValueToCompare() );
    }

    @Test
    public void commonPerformanceTest() {
        assertTimeout( 1000, () -> createInstance().value() );
    }

    protected void assertTimeout(long mills, Runnable e){
        /* add your imple */
    }

    protected abstract MyInterface<T> createInstance();

    protected abstract T getValueToCompare();
}

public class MyClassTest extends AbstractTest<String>{

    @Override
    protected MyInterface<String> createInstance(){
        return new MyClass();
    }

    @Override
    protected String getValueToCompare(){
        return "hi";
    }

    @Test
    public void specificTest() {
        /* your code */
    }
}
```